# Show $E[(M_n-M_m)M_k]=0$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales

> Let $M_n$ be an $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ - martingale on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$, show that
> $$E[(M_n-M_m)M_k]=0,\qquad 0\leq k\leq m \leq n.$$

I want to know if this is correct:

By the multi-step property of a martingale we have that
$$E[M_n|\mathcal{F}_m]=M_m\implies E[M_n-M_m|\mathcal{F}_m]=0,\qquad 0\leq m\leq n.$$

Multiplying my $M_k$ gives
$$M_kE[M_n-M_m|\mathcal{F}_m]=0.$$
Since $\mathcal{F}_k\subseteq \mathcal{F}_m$, then
$$E[(M_n-M_m)M_k|\mathcal{F}_m]=0$$
and taking expectations gives
$$E[E[(M_n-M_m)M_k|\mathcal{F}_m]]=E[(M_n-M_m)M_k]=0.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me.  The only criticism I'd make is that your last line has the wrong order on the equalities, and
$$E[(M_n-M_m)M_k]=E[E[(M_n-M_m)M_k|\mathcal{F}_m]]=0$$
reflects your logical argument better (to someone who knows the subject, your intent is clear, but to someone learning it, it might look like you're begging the question).

---

On a sidenote, I'm assuming your martingale is $L^2$.  Otherwise, there's a problem when you first write $E[(M_n-M_m)M_k|\mathcal{F}_m]=0$